# URL with div identifier and query string does not load

Tags: html, url-rewriting

I have a URL something like:

```
http://www.example.com/something.html#carousel-nav4?TrackID=00000
```

The page does not load the content of `#carousel-nav4` instead an empty div.

Since we are using the query string for tracking purposes it is important for us to retain it.

Is there any way that I can get the div to show up with the query string appended?

Answer (score 0):

The bookmark always goes last. In your example the link will look for a div with the id `carousel-nav4?TrackID=00000`, and not `carousel-nav4`as you want, hence the empty output.

You should re-write your link like this:

```
http://www.example.com/something.html?TrackID=00000#carousel-nav4
```